# How can I run two scripts at same time in one linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

In my package.json I have these two scripts, but, to run them I need to open two different terminals:

```
"start": "nodemon server.js --ignore public --ignore frontend",
"dev": "webpack -w"
```

I have tried to run both at the same time with this script:

```
"dev": "nodemon server.js --ignore public --ignore frontend ; webpack -w"
```

and

```
"dev": "nodemon server.js --ignore public --ignore frontend && webpack -w"
```

But, neither of them worked. Is there any way to make this work in one terminal? Also, sorry for my bad English, I'm still studying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use construction like:

```
nodemon server.js --ignore public --ignore frontend & webpack -w
```

Using `;` mean consecutive execution, `&&` mean again consecutive execution and second command will execute only if exit code from first execution is 0.

With above example you put first execution in background and start second one.

I suppose `dev:` and `start:` are just labels